# Can the editor highlight/mark local variables in contrast to global variables?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, delphi-10.3-rio

Is there an option in the IDE (or a free plug-in/tool) to mark local variables in a different color/font in contrast to global variables?
If NO, how do you handle this? By var-name?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such option in the IDE and I'm not aware of any IDE plug-in that does it.

I use a naming convention (a prefix) to distinguish between various variable scopes:

```
G       for Global
F       for Field (variable in a class)
A       for Argument
Nothing for local variable
```

There are numerous other way to do it. Each developer has his own rules.